# VBA Word vbscript Regex pattern

Tags: regex, vba, ms-word

I need a vbscript Regex pattern in a Word VBA macro for the following:

1. any number of names (words having their first letter capitalized) separated by a space or hyphen,
2. followed by any number or spaces followed by "De" or "de" followed by any number of spaces,
3. then followed by any number of names (words having their first letter capitalized).

I have the following pattern, but it doesn't work, I get a syntax error from the compiler.
"([A-Z][a-z](?:[ -][A-Z][a-z])) ([Dd]e) ([A-Z][a-z](?:[ -][A-Z][a-z]))"

Later I have changed the first group to this new pattern:
"<[A-Z][a-z]*[ -]"

Comment: I actually have straight quotes in my code.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the VBA code that you are using. Using the following, I didn't receive a *compiler* error here: Sub vbssearch()
Dim S As String
Dim vm As New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
S = "([A-Z][a-z](?:[ -][A-Z][a-z])) ([Dd]e) ([A-Z][a-z](?:[ -][A-Z][a-z]))"
vm.Execute S

End Sub